# Is reading a bool faster than reading a string?

Tags: ios, performance, uiviewcontroller

I have a very basic array that is appended with a value depending on whether a user hits one button or the other. A function will be called in the `viewDidLoad()` method of my app and will perform a function depending on the value in the array (it will differ depending on what index I am looking at, obviously, but lets just focus on the first index). I can either append the array with a "Yes"/"No", `String`s, or with true/false, `bool`s. Since the function is relatively simple, I recognize that this might not make a huge deal, but I figured why not optimize whenever I can. Is it faster to have `if` (or `switch`) statements check for `bool` comparisons than `string` comparisons? Or is it the other way around?

Comment: Adding `android` and `java` tags deduced from the content of the question.

Comment: Removed `android` and `java` tags as it appears to be an iOS development question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be better for performance to do bool compares since it compares exactly 1 value (e.g 0 = 0 or 0 = 1), as where string has to compare every character in the string to find the match or no match.

TL:DR bool comparison is faster than string comparison

Answer (score 1):

Because reading a boolean is essentially binary options, e.g True/False, rather than a comparison, it is quicker than doing a string comparison. Although it's only marginal in this scenario, it would certainly be beneficial to read booleans for much larger computations.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question you asked - yes, comparing `bool` is more efficient than comparing strings.

To answer the question you should be asking - optimize for performance where you have bottlenecks, optimize for simplicity/readability/maintainability everywhere else. If you don't know whether that part is a bottleneck, learn how to measure it.

In this specific case the efficient and the simple cases may be the same, but the very question is misguided - don't attempt optimizing for performance where it doesn't matter.